# Set OpenCV's iOS CvVideoCamera default fps above 30

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, opencv

Whenever trying to set the CvVideoCamera's default fps to above 30 it stays set to 30 fps. It allows me to set it lower, but nothing above 30 fps. I'm using an iPhone 7 so I know it is capable of shooting 1920x1080 video at 60fps. I have looked into using AVCaptureSession, but OpenCV's CvVideoCamera allows easy access and processing of individual frames so I would like to stick with it if at all possible.

`self.videoCamera = [[CvVideoCamera alloc]initWithParentView:self.videoPreviewView];
 self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureDevicePosition = AVCaptureDevicePositionBack;
 self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureSessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPreset1920x1080;
 self.videoCamera.defaultAVCaptureVideoOrientation = AVCaptureVideoOrientationLandscapeLeft;
 self.videoCamera.defaultFPS = 60; //This still sets it to 30 FPS
 self.videoCamera.grayscaleMode = NO;
 self.videoCamera.delegate = self;`

Comment: Did u get any answer, i am using iPhone 7 Plus and having the same problem.

Comment: I didn't. What I ended up doing was using an AVCaptureSession and modifying the camera settings there. [Here](http://altitudelabs.com/blog/real-time-filter/) is a decent tutorial on how to set this up and extract the frames. What you do with OpenCV is up to you.